# IActionContextAccessor equivalent in Razor Pages

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages

In ASP.NET MVC Core 2.0 you can inject the `ActionContext`, into services, using the `IActionContextAccessor` interface.

I would like to do the same in Razor Pages but there isn't (from what I can see) an `IPageContextAccessor`.

Doe anyone know how to inject the `PageContext` into a service?

Answer (score 1):

The `IActionContextAccessor` does work in Razor Pages. The reason it wasn't working was because I hadn't registered the `IActionContextAccessor` service[1]:

```
services.AddSingleton<IActionContextAccessor, ActionContextAccessor>();
```

Note: it *must* be registered as a Singleton.

[1] https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/3936#issuecomment-194367440